# Problem with UTL_HTTP Package in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, http, plsql, httprequest, oracle-apex

I have a problem with APEX. We have two servers. One (with running Oracle APEX) is the university server, which we have only access to the workspace. The other is my Linux Computer at home, which acts as a server (running Tomcat with Jasperreports container). I want to send a UTL_HTTP request from the APEX machine to the Jasperreports machine. There is a button, which triggers a process with following code:

```
 begin
  xlib_jasperreports.set_report_url('http://X.X.X.X:8080/JasperReportsIntegration/report');
  xlib_jasperreports.show_report (p_rep_name => :p5_rep_name,
                                  p_rep_format => :p5_rep_format,
                                  p_data_source => :p5_data_source,
                                  p_out_filename => :p5_out_filename,
                                  p_rep_locale => :p5_rep_locale,
                                  p_rep_encoding => :p5_rep_encoding,
                                  p_additional_params => :p5_additional_params);

  -- stop rendering of the current APEX page
  apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
end;
```

After 20 to 30 seconds after I pushed the triggering button I get following errormessage:

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1029 ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out

I checked the set_report_url function by setting a common url . And it worked. Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance,
Haniball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter version of Oracle have Network ACL security, so it might be that the schema owner doesn't have privileges to access that particular URL. However I'd expect a security violation for that.

Another alternative is that it is being blocked by a firewall between the database server and your home machine. It is possible (likely) that the database server machine has been set up to only allow a small list of sites to be accessed (or none at all). You may also have a firewall on your home machine that prevents access from machines not on a list of IP addresses/ranges.

Try some basic UTL_HTTP actions against a variety of sites (eg the google.com home page), and see what response you get.

---

Missed the obvious UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout. It may be that the job takes a bit too long at the home server.

Comment: Cannot be ACL because it gives an proper error message of that.